# unable to get the presProps.xml in my generated PPTX document

Tags: docx4j

PresentationMLPackage presentationMLPackage = PresentationMLPackage.createPackage();

```
    // Need references to these parts to create a slide
    // Please note that these parts *already exist* - they are
    // created by createPackage() above.  See that method
    // for instruction on how to create and add a part.
    MainPresentationPart pp = (MainPresentationPart)presentationMLPackage.getParts().getParts().get(
            new PartName("/ppt/presentation.xml"));     
    SlideLayoutPart layoutPart = (SlideLayoutPart)presentationMLPackage.getParts().getParts().get(
            new PartName("/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml"));

    PresentationPropertiesPart presProp = (PresentationPropertiesPart)presentationMLPackage.getParts().getParts().get(
            new PartName("/ppt/preseProps.xml"));

    // OK, now we can create a slide
    SlidePart slidePart = presentationMLPackage.createSlidePart(pp, layoutPart, 
            new PartName("/ppt/slides/slide1.xml"));

    // Create and add shape
    Shape sample = ((Shape)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(SAMPLE_SHAPE, Context.jcPML) );
    slidePart.getJaxbElement().getCSld().getSpTree().getSpOrGrpSpOrGraphicFrame().add(sample);

    // All done: save it
    presentationMLPackage.save(new java.io.File(outputfilepath));

    System.out.println("\n\n done .. saved " + outputfilepath);
```

i have used above CreateHelloworld.java  example to create a pptx document . I have modified it so that the created pptx package has presProps.xml. But it is not generated when i execute the above code....Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment at the top of code you have copy/pasted, your code assumes the PresentationPropertiesPart already exists.

It doesn't, so you have to create it first.  The following ought to do the trick:

```
PresentationPropertiesPart ppPart = new PresentationPropertiesPart();       
pp.addTargetPart(ppPart);
PresentationPr presProp = Context.getpmlObjectFactory().createPresentationPr();
ppPart.setJaxbElement(presProp);
```